# How to automatically extract data as text file using Tableau JS API

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I used showExportDataDialog() to export data using Tableau JS API . This renders a pop-up window showing a link where we can click to dowload all data as text file.

But Is there a way where we can directly download the data as .csv with out having this manual click event using JS API?

Thanks,
Arathi